# Woher kommt der Gebrauch von "umsetzen" für das Erledigen von Aufgaben in der IT?

Tags: etymology

Bei der Softwareentwicklung sagt man oft

```
Diese Kundenwünsche wurden umgesetzt.
```

um auszudrücken, dass bestimmte Aufgaben erledigt sind. Wo kommt dieser Sprachgebrauch her?

Comment: Die Frage ist insofern ein bisschen schräg, als die Verwendung des Verbs "etwas umsetzen" im Sinne von *ein Vorhaben ausführen*, *einen Auftrag erledigen* überhaupt nicht IT-spezifisch ist. Der Ausdruck wird schon seit jeher so verwendet und in allen möglichen Fach- und Wirtschaftsbereichen. Überall halt, wo man erst etwas plant und dann... umsetzt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"umsetzen" hat mindestens drei Bedeutungsfelder:

- Änderung der Position ("einen Baum umsetzen", "Umsetzung eines Beamten")
- Waren verkaufen ("doppelt so viel wie letztes Jahr umsetzen")
- etwas verwirklichen oder realisieren

Diese letzte Verwendung (als "Positionsänderung" im übertragenen Sinne, nämlich vom Fiktiven ins Reale) ist schon recht alt, man hat lange vor der Softwareentwicklung Pläne, Verordnungen und Ideen umgesetzt, und die Wendung "etwas in die Praxis umsetzen" gibt es auch schon lange.

Hier ein Beispiel aus dem 19. Jh.

> Es ist der Fluch der Vornehmen, daß sich ihnen die höchsten irdischen Genüsse in kahle, schale Bedürfnisse, die sie immer befriedigen können, umsetzen.

Christian Friedrich Hebbel (1813–1863)

http://www.gutzitiert.de/zitat_autor_christian_friedrich_hebbel_thema_erfuellung_zitat_7406.html